# Macro para tranformar TIF a PDF con Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, macros, visual-basic

Estoy intentando crear una macro que recorra carpetas y sub carpetas para identificar imágenes .TIF y convertirlas en PDF con la ayuda de AdobeAcrobat.

Si bien la macro en parte funciona porque recorre, encuentra y abre correctamente los archivos, al momento de Guardar como PDF me arroja errores y no sé por qué. Probé varias opciones pero no doy con la solución.

Les dejo el código:

```
Sub ConvertirTIFaPDF_Acrobat()
    Dim CarpetaSeleccionada As String
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim Carpeta As Object
    Dim SubCarpeta As Object
    Dim Archivo As Object
    Dim PDFFileName As String
    Dim AcrobatApp As Object
    Dim AcrobatAVDoc As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
        ' Seleccionar carpeta
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Title = "Selecciona una carpeta"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                CarpetaSeleccionada = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                MsgBox "No se ha seleccionado ninguna carpeta."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
        
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Carpeta = FileSystem.GetFolder(CarpetaSeleccionada)
    
    ' Inicializar la aplicación de Adobe Acrobat
    Set AcrobatApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    
        For Each SubCarpeta In Carpeta.SubFolders
        
            For Each Archivo In SubCarpeta.Files
                ' Verificar la extensión .TIF
                If LCase(FileSystem.GetExtensionName(Archivo.Path)) = "tif" Then
                
                    ' Abrir en Adobe
                    Set AcrobatAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
                    AcrobatAVDoc.Open Archivo.Path, ""
                    AcrobatApp.Show
                    
                    ' Guardar el archivo TIF como PDF en la misma ubicación
                    PDFFileName = SubCarpeta.Path & "\" & FileSystem.GetBaseName(Archivo.Name) & ".pdf"
                    
                    AcrobatApp.SaveAs PDFFileName, "com.adobe.acrobat.pdf" '(<<--- esta linea no funciona deberia guardar pero no)
                    
                    AcrobatAVDoc.Close True
                    
                    i = i + 1
                    
                End If
            Next Archivo
        Next SubCarpeta
    
    AcrobatApp.Exit
    Set AcrobatApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "La conversión de TIF a PDF se ha completado. Se convirtieron " & i & " archivos."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! arroja errores.. que errores???

Comment: ¿en qué parte del código sucede lo que comentas? ¿Probaste a ejecutarlo con F8 paso a paso para ver por qué sucede?

Comment: Hola, hasta donde recuerdo, cuando se usa el objeto Acrobat, este no tiene el método SaveAs para usar directamente, sino que hay que generar otro objeto JavaScript para a través de él poder usar "SaveAs".

Comment: el error lo arroja en esta linea "AcrobatApp.SaveAs PDFFileName" error 438 si estuve viendo que no soporta la propiedad save as hoy haciendo otras pruebas aplique la funcion AcrobatApp.MenuItemExecute "SaveAs" y sirvio para abrir el cuadro de opciones de adobe pero no logro que guarde el archivo

Comment: @AbrahamValencia como se generaria el obj JS para usarlo ?

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que en Preferencias - Seguridad (Mejorada) de tu Adobe PRO no esté activada dicha seguridad; segundo, agrega un objeto JS a tu macro y usa así el método Saveas:

```
Sub ConvertirTIFaPDF_Acrobat()
    Dim CarpetaSeleccionada As String
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim Carpeta As Object
    Dim SubCarpeta As Object
    Dim Archivo As Object
    Dim PDFFileName As String
    Dim AcrobatApp As Object
    Dim AcrobatAVDoc As Object
    Dim i As Integer
     Dim objAcroPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Dim boResult As Boolean
    Dim objJSO As Object
        ' Seleccionar carpeta
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Title = "Selecciona una carpeta"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                CarpetaSeleccionada = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                MsgBox "No se ha seleccionado ninguna carpeta."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
        
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Carpeta = FileSystem.GetFolder(CarpetaSeleccionada)
    
    ' Inicializar la aplicación de Adobe Acrobat
    Set AcrobatApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    
        For Each SubCarpeta In Carpeta.SubFolders
        
            For Each Archivo In SubCarpeta.Files
                ' Verificar la extensión .TIF
                If LCase(FileSystem.GetExtensionName(Archivo.Path)) = "tiff" Then
                
                    ' Abrir en Adobe
                    Set AcrobatAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
                    AcrobatAVDoc.Open Archivo.Path, ""
                    AcrobatApp.Show
                    
                    '''''
                     Set objAcroPDDoc = AcrobatAVDoc.GetPDDoc

                        'Set the JS Object - Java Script Object.
                        Set objJSO = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
                    
                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                       
                    
                    ' Guardar el archivo TIF como PDF en la misma ubicación
                    PDFFileName = SubCarpeta.Path & "\" & FileSystem.GetBaseName(Archivo.Name) & ".pdf"
                    Debug.Print PDFFileName
                  '  AcrobatApp.SaveAs PDFFileName, "com.adobe.acrobat.pdf" '(<<--- esta linea no funciona deberia guardar pero no)
                          objJSO.SaveAs (PDFFileName)
                    AcrobatAVDoc.Close True
                    
                    i = i + 1
                    
                End If
            Next Archivo
        Next SubCarpeta
    
    AcrobatApp.Exit
    Set AcrobatApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "La conversión de TIF a PDF se ha completado. Se convirtieron " & i & " archivos."
    
End Sub
```